# Fitting a dropdown menu in a smaller display

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

Ok, i have a problem which i couldn't figure out yet.

So, basically i'm using bootstrap and i'm trying to create a section for the user if he wants to sign up.

The problem is, if i have an iphone 3GS and wants to enter to my page,
the dropdown menu is too big and cannot fit on the screen ! (As shown below)

[image: Example here]

The dropdown menu i added, is the one from bootstrap.

Is there any way for solving that ?

/**--------------------------------------**/

After adding the drop menu css for media max-width 4xx px.
[image: with the css you said]

Comment: Try adding `word-wrap: break-word;` to break the line into two lines?

Comment: doesn't work on p elements :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .dropdown-menu has a min-width but not a max-width. It will be the width of the content + padding. To limit the width on small devices only do the following. Correct the width of the .dropdown-menu parent and then using the same specificity used in the Bootstrap CSS allow the link itself to wrap:

```
@media (max-width:480px) {
  .dropdown-menu {
    width:90%;
 }

  .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    white-space: normal;
 }

}
```

Make the max-width value your own, this is just an idea.

You can always see why a selector behaves the way it does by looking at the unpacked CSS.

## [Line 3423](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L3423)

Comment: After doing it like you said, the content of that a element, even if it fits with his parent (which is the li element in this case). The text inside of the a element is continuing with the same issues.

Comment: Thank you Christina !!! :) It works now ! :) Should i make a bug problem to bootstrap ?
By the way i saw your website and i really liked the design !

Comment: I would make it a feature request for v 4 coming out pretty soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
overflow: hidden;
position:absolute;
right: 0;
max-width:yourmaxwidth;
```

Comment: but then, you will be hiding the text which is not the behavior that i want.
I want that the text must fit on the screen in this cases :/

Comment: I did that to my .dropdown-menu and same thing as i said before, hiding the text :/

Answer (score 0):

Use this css style, It will work:-

```
@media (max-width:480px) {
  .dropdown-menu {
    width:90%;
    white-space:normal;
 }
}
```